# Django 3.2 how to add model decimal fields together inside model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to add all the decimalfields numbers together to form a sum inside the model

this is my model

```
class Ataskaita(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ataskaitos'

    bendrija = models.ForeignKey(Bendrija, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="ataskaita")

    atlyginimas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    sodra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    vmi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    pvm_saskaitos_kvitas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    bankines_operacijos = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    
    sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

and I want to add all the fields (atlyginimas, sodra, vmi, pvm_saskaitos_kvitas, bankines_operacijos) together so I have all of their total

I looked around stackoverflow and I think the only way to do it is to create a method, but I already tried it, and it wouldn't work as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django models are just python classes, so adding arbitrary methods like this should work fine:

```
class Ataskaita(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ataskaitos'

    bendrija = models.ForeignKey(Bendrija, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="ataskaita")

    atlyginimas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    sodra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    vmi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    pvm_saskaitos_kvitas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    bankines_operacijos = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return sum([self.atlyginimas, self.sodra, self.vmi, self.pvm_saskaitos_kvitas, self.bankines_operacijos])
```

You can instruct your serializers to display read-only properties with something like this:

```
class Ataskaita(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sum = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Ataskaita
        fields = '__all__'
```

Does that do what you wanted?

Comment: the property worked as I wanted to yes, thank you very much, but I tried looking up some stuff about the serializers thing you and google wasn't very helpful so not sure what that part of the code accomplishes

Comment: @Sir.Breezy If you want to display a `Ataskaita` object in a webpage, the serializer will convert it from it's python representation to something that can be displayed. By default, Django serializers will display the object's fields (decimalFields, ForeignKeys). In this case, you might also want to display the `sum`, so we need to instruct the Serializer to do so, and let it know this is a read-only field.